# Duplicity Backup: Errno 104 Connection reset by peer when backing up to Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use Duplicity to run backups from my local server to Amazon S3. This has been working fine for over a year. Three days ago, I started getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/backends/_boto_multi.py", line 204, in _upload
num_cb=max(2, 8 * bytes / (1024 * 1024))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/multipart.py", line 260, in upload_part_from_file
query_args=query_args, size=size)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1291, in set_contents_from_file
chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 748, in send_file
chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 949, in _send_file_internal
query_args=query_args
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 664, in make_request
retry_handler=retry_handler
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1068, in make_request
retry_handler=retry_handler)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 939, in _mexe
request.body, request.headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 842, in sender
http_conn.send(chunk)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 805, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 229, in sendall
v = self.send(data[count:])
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 198, in send
v = self._sslobj.write(data)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

These are still occurring even after I tried the following:

--added "s3-use-multiprocessing" to my script file

--added the following two lines to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 512000
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 512000
```

-- ran sysctl -p to start using the above.

Three days ago, I started running Duplicity on a couple of other servers, backing up to a different bucket on the same account. That was when THIS server started reporting connection reset errors. The other servers are working fine, and all of them are using the same versions of Duplicity and Python. They are in different locations on different subnets, but that shouldn't make a difference.

The original chunk size on the problem server was 25MB. It's 250MB on the others. What else can I look for? I'm guessing Amazon is resetting the connection, but why single out this server?

Comment: Is the server inside AWS or outside?  Three days ago (Monday, 2/8, I believe it was), there were significant connectivity disruptions into us-east-1 due to an external Internet provider's routing configuration error, and round trip times for me, from another collo in Virginia into AWS jumped from 2ms to 180ms, as Virginia to Virgina traffic began routing through Seattle, WA.  That issue cleared up later in the day.

Comment: The server I'm trying to back up is outside AWS, but it is being backed up to us-east-1. Think it's related to the disruption you mentioned? I'm not having this issue on my other servers, but again, they're at a different location (also outside AWS).

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @Yajo: It turned out to be the service disruption described above. It's been working fine since that was resolved.